# Godaddy CORS issue - Angular 7 - Laravel 5

Tags: php, angular, laravel, apache

I have developed application in **Angular 7** and APIs in **Laravel 5.7**.

For CORS issue, I have also installed **barryvdh/laravel-cors** package in Laravel and its working fine on local.

But when I deployed these both applications on Godaddy single hosting, that is **Starter Linux Hosting with cPanel**

1. Angular app in main directory **public_html**
2. Laravel APIs in **public_html/api** directory which points to
   **public_html/api/public**

APIs are not working and I am seeing this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.example.com/api/documentations?page=1' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request
```

I have seen lot of answers on stackoverflow and on other sources, nothing seems to be working for me.

I tried adding headers to **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

As well as directly to **index.php** but with no luck.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

Any idea or help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a HTTP to HTTPS redirect in place? If so, you need to point your API calls at the HTTPS version.

Comment: I have http redirect

Comment: OK, so as the message states, a CORS request can't be redirected like that. Your API calls should *start* with HTTPS instead of relying on the redirect.

Comment: I am getting crazy trying to fix the same issue you experienced. Is there any way you can provide code about the fix you've performed? So, I  don't have a call to https. So, I don't have that situation but the same error.

Comment: In case you can provide how did you leave the config/cors.php file and I'll try to get a better idea. I tried anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Since you have a HTTP to HTTPS redirect in place, and your API calls are trying to access `http://api.example.com/api/documentations?page=1`, they're going to fail, because (as the message states) you can't redirect a CORS preflight.

Update your code to make the API calls over HTTPS.

Comment: @ceejaoz I don't have SSL certificates on my server to call APIs over HTTPS . Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Sure, if your API doesn't have HTTPS, stop redirecting it to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ceejayoz for your valuable comments and answer. I am able to find the issue

I am having two **.htaccess** files. For main domain, one at

```
public_html/.htaccess
```

and another for subdomain at

```
public_html/api/public/.htaccess
```

The one at **public_html/.htaccess** having this line to protect the files inside the **public_html/api** directory from root access of main domain

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/api/.*$
```

When I commented/removed this line, APIs started working but files inside **public_html/api** directory were not secure.

Then to secure the files, I created one more file at **public_html/api/.htaccess** and added these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^public/ - [F,NC]
```

**And I achieved both:** APIs are working and files inside **public_html/api** are secured.